# How do you fix a badly cropped portrait?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, crop

I am making a Dota 2 (video game) fan site. I want to use portraits of the characters of the game, but the game provides portraits that look really awkward when placed on a website:

[image]

His head is sliced at the middle and so is the beard. The bottom and left of the photo give a very unnatural straight-as-an-arrow edge to the photo. Unlike these crops which will blend nicely into a website:

[image]

How do I go about making the first crop look more "Smooth" like the second type of crop?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a good source image, either you find it, probably grabing some screenshoots, invent it again, making a new image, or live with what you have.

P.S. The crop of the circular photos are not good either, there is much space above the head.

The eyes are not recomended to be centered in the frame.

---

On your image, try a border, a thin border, try a shadow.

That particular image looks strange because all that white on tle right side. A border or shadow could define more the framing.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why straight as an arrow edges look awkward?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had no idea, what the wanted smoothness exactly does mean. So I quessed and this is the result:

[image: smoothed version of the imag]

The receipe for Adobe Photoshop:

- increase canvas size to about 200%
- add a grey background layer; it makes white hair visible (note: you had a png photo with transparency)
- make a square selection that covers the meaningful part of the portrait
- stretch the selected area to circular form by warping; this simulates having a photo taken from much closer position instead of being cropped to smaller size, add a little spherizing for the credibility
- make a new circular selection that holds exactly the result of the warping
- delete everything outside the circle in both layers
- merge the layers
- crop the picture to minimum size square that covers the circle
- save the result

We old bastards easily ignore thislike problems, but I at least try to avoid it. Have your fun!